# Can't send mails with nodemailer, using my gmail account - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer

I'm trying to send mails through my web application using NodeMailer and Gmail.
I got everything needed - clientId, clientSecret, refreshToken and accessToken - followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJ44WA_eV8E) tutorial.

Once I try to execute the code I get this message:

> Error: Mail command failed: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn
>   more at 530 5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError
>   f12sm13931996wmf.28 - gsmtp
>       at SMTPConnection._formatError    code: 'EENVELOPE',   response: '530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n' +
>       '530 5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError f12sm13931996wmf.28 - gsmtp',   responseCode: 530,   command: 'MAIL
>   FROM'

Tried googling it and nothing solved my prolem.

Answer (score 0):

Two Possibilities:
May be OAuth2.0 authenticated account & Sender Email  you provide are different.
Other one is Allow Less secure apps is off .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need to allow less secure apps on your Google account. Can do it in following link, https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

After that, the message that you have send with Nodemailer should be on spam. The same thing happens with the Sendgrid service, you need to allow the less secure apps.

I hope and it has served you :)